# glibc double free or corruption (out) without the use of malloc

Tags: c, glibc, scanf

I keep getting this error 
          glibc double free or corruption (out) error
and so far everything i've read on it has been due to an improper use of malloc, which would  point to memory space, however, i'm not using malloc. I think its Something about how fscanf is accepting the stream. But nothing I'm reading on fscanf makes any sense to me in relation to the error I'm getting. Here's the code.

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <fcntl.h>
      #include <sys.stat.h>
      #inlcude <termios.h>
      #inlcude <string.h>

      #define BAUDRATE B115200
      #define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyS0"

      main()
      {
        int n;

        FILE *file

        file = fopen(MODEMDEVICE, "a");

        if(file == NULL){
                         printf("initiating error\n);
                         return 1;
                         }

           FILE *fp;
           fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "a");

                while(1){
                         fscanf(file, "%02x", &n);
                         fprintf(fp, "%d", n);
                         fclose(fp);
                         fclose(file);
                         }
        }
```

my intention of this code is to take data streams from a serial port and and store them in a text file. Any ideas on why i'm getting this error?

Comment: "I am not using malloc" -- yes, you *are* (indirectly) -- `fopen` uses it (and `fclose` uses `free`), so misuse of `fopen` may (and did) manifest itself as a `malloc` failure.

Answer (score 3):

The `while(1)` loop reads data from one file and writes it to the other file, but then closes the files. Once the files are closed you can't read from or write to them anymore, though your `while` loop tries again.

Answer (score 1):

This code won't compile.  It is missing a ";".

It's also opening both files with mode "a"; but surely you meant to open one for reading.

Anyway the bug is that you're calling fclose in the loop.